# html5 fullscreen

Tags: html5

Watching videos via Tor in fullscreen stutters.
Is there a way to fix it?

I tried enabling hardware acceleration but it still stutters.
I know that flash player is disabled because of security reasons.

But what if I set up a personal bridge on a second computer with tails and connect to that bridge with tor and flash player? Would it make it safer?

Comment: Is it possible the issue is A) connection speed or B) processing power? If you download the video and open it in Tor Browser by browsing to the file on disk and playing it, does it still stutter in fullscreen playback? If you play the file from disk outside of Tor Browser does it stutter in fullscreen playback?

Comment: i think it was the processing power. I tried it today and somehow it worked without performance issues. i guess my pc was overheating the last time i tried it or sth like that. But now i dont experience performance issues with tor and html5. Thanks for your advice on how to search for the problem!